# States used in lossless quantum compression?

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, communication

I was reading about quantum compression in [this article](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2007.3567.3571) and have some doubts regarding an example mentioned. Specifically, I have two questions:

1. In example they represented $|a\rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}|10\rangle +\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{15}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}|11\rangle$. How can they call this a quantum state given that the sum of square magnitudes of the amplitudes is not equal to one?
2. If they are compressing kets ($|10\rangle$ to $|1\rangle $) then what is  the point of the amplitudes $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$?

Comment: I'd add that the author says the state $|a\rangle$ is a mixed state. Weird.

Comment: can you reformat the question to focus it on a single point? The stackexchange format is tailored for laser-focused posts; feel free to edit the question accordingly. It would also help to make the post self-contained by sketching what exactly is meant in the linked text with "compression". A meaningful title would also help

Comment: Well, the question 1 is enough to raise doubts that the _Journal of Applied Sciences_ is a meaningful scientific journal.

Comment: @kludg The publisher "science alert" is on [Beall's list of potential predatory journals/publishers](https://beallslist.net/).

Comment: A serious note on the first question though, it is possible the author is just writing the state "up to normalization". So you just have to normalize the given state. Would this make sense in the context of the paper?

Comment: Well, it could be unnormalized. But why $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ factor? Is it a joke? I have strong suspition that the whole article is a joke, partly copy-pasted from other sources, partly nonsense.

Comment: @Rammus If we normalize we have to store data for each vector to recover the original, Then it effects the compression right?

Comment: @kludg  The main reference for this is (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0105026.pdf) this article which does almost same.

Comment: I understand classical Huffman coding, I coded Huffman algorithm then I was a programmer. I guess that the article pretend to propose an adaptive quantum Huffman coding algorithm (and it makes sense). But the article raises too much questions.

Comment: But they both had the same kind of example with out normalized quantum states.

Comment: I agree that this is very confusing. I've emailed the author of the article and if I hear back, will post the response.